# GeometryEngine Offset or GeodesicBuffer - to get minimal corners.net

Tags: arcgis-10.2, buffer, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

We have a a polygon which might have between 8 and 20 points, which we need to draw a boundary around, that is at least 1km around at all points.  The **restriction is that we can't increase the the number of vertices dramatically** (or better still at all).

If I use GeometryEngine.GeodesicBuffer() to do this, it generates rounded corners at external vertices and hence greatly increases the number of vertices.

So I used GeometryEngine.Offset(). The Offset() has an OffsetType, which allows me to specify Square, and this returns basically the same number of vertices as I started with. However during testing it became obvious that the offset function has issues with the WGS84 spatial reference. Our East-West coordinates are OK, but any coordinates in the North-South plane are extended by 25% (which may be a factor of the latitude our tests are at).

So, the question is,

Can I use GeodesicBuffer in a way that I can stop the corners being rounded, OR do I keep using Offset, but convert/project into a different spatial reference (and if so which one)?

Note: Using the .Net framework of arcgis.

Comment: Just thinking aloud, can you use the extent of the buffer you create, it will full fill your requirement of being at least 1Km away from all points and be a polygon composed of only 4 points?

Comment: @Hornbydd will not be optimised at all. It needs to follow the original shape as much as possible, but not generate rounded corners.